# How to click a lot of elements in Javascript without errors?

Tags: javascript, python

I have been trying to download all USA and CANADA servers here on Nord VPN website: https://nordvpn.com/ovpn/

I tried to manually download it but it is time consuming to scroll down every time and identify each US related servers, so i just wrote simple Javascript that can be run on Chrome Inspect Element Console:

```
var servers = document.getElementsByClassName("mr-2");
var inc_servers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
  var main_server = servers[i];
  var server = servers[i].innerText;
  if(server.includes("ca")){
        var parent_server = main_server.parentElement.parentElement;
        parent_server.querySelector(".Button.Button--primary.Button--small").click();
        inc_servers.push(server);
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(inc_servers));
```

I also wrote simple python script that automatically click "save" file:

```
while True:
    try:
        app2 = pywinauto.Application().connect(title=u'Save As', found_index=0)
        app2.SaveAs.Save.click()
    except:
        pass
```

It gets all the elements, it works there, however, when I let javascript click each element, maybe because of too many elements, it returns an error:

VM15575:8 Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging. See https://crbug.com/1038223. Command line switch --disable-ipc-flooding-protection can be used to bypass the protection

Are there any other best alternative for my problem? Or maybe how to fix the error message above? I tried running this command in my command prompt: switch --disable-ipc-flooding-protection

but it returns also an error: 'switch' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I only know basic Javascript and Python. Thanks

Comment: ok i think i can use selenium to scrape all the US server names, then access each server using this link "https://downloads.nordcdn.com/configs/files/ovpn_legacy/servers/" + "ca1504.nordvpn.com" + ".udp1194.ovpn"

Comment: Whenever I try to run your JavaScript in my console, only one file gets downloaded. It seems random, e.g the first time I ran the script "us-ca73...." downloaded, however the second time "us-ca47..." downloaded. It this expected behaviour?

Comment: Yeah, i created an array "inc_servers" all of the elements inside the array should be downloaded.

Comment: `VM15575:8 Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging. See https://crbug.com/1038223. Command line switch --disable-ipc-flooding-protection can be used to bypass the protection` is not actually an error, it's a warning. There's nothing wrong with the code, it's just the dev tools telling you that this is kinda "not good" as a solution but it still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So right off the bat, your program is simply downloading files too fast.

Adding a small delay between each file download allows your JavaScript to run.

```
var servers = document.getElementsByClassName("mr-2");
var inc_servers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
  var main_server = servers[i];
  var server = servers[i].innerText;
  if(server.includes("ca")){
        var parent_server = main_server.parentElement.parentElement;
        // Add 1 second delay between each download (fast enough on my computer.. Might be too fast for yours.)
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        parent_server.querySelector(".Button.Button--primary.Button--small").click();


  }
}
// Remove the logging. Just tell the user that it's worked
console.log("Done downloading all files.");
```

This is more of a temporary solution, but this script seems like it only needs to be run once, so it'll work for now.

(your python code runs fine. Nothing to do there)

Hope this helped.